# In MS Excel, how can I export a pair of columns as a text file of ordered pairs in brackets, separated by commas?

Tags: list, csv, export, coordinates, brackets

What I have:

| 1   | 3   |

| 2   | 4   |

| 3   | 2   |

| 4   | 8   |

| 5   | 1   |

What I want:

((1,3),(2,4),(3,2),(4,8),(5,1))

How can I do that?

I tried exporting to .csv but couldn't manage to include the brackets. Not sure what else to try.